# Ubuntu 13.10 problems in apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, 13.10

I recently install Ubuntu 13.10, but I had several difficulties on installing several programs from 'Ubuntu Software Center'. I tried to update the repositories but I get the follow result:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I want to install Seaview, Dropbox, Terminator and the IDLE of python 2.7, but I can't since I get 'There isn't a software package called `<program to install>` in your current software sources' or 'Available from the "multiverse" source. However, for this last one, when I do click over "Use this Source" nothing happens.

I need help. Tx to all.

Comment: Possibly a bug.

Comment: Try changing the Download server.

Comment: Check ipv6 with this command `[ -f /proc/net/if_inet6 ] && echo 'IPv6 ready system!' || echo 'No IPv6 support found! Compile the kernel!!'` and expand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can't connect via ipv6, try to disable ipv6 first via network manager ofr temporary or editing sysctl for temporary

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

press i, add this values

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

press esc then press :wq

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the Download Server

   - [Follow these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server)
   - Don't forget `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install your software

   ```
   sudo apt-get install seaview
   sudo apt-get install terminator
   sudo apt-get install idle-python2.7
   ```
3. Install Dropbox

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ saucy main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list' 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install dropbox
   ```

Comment: @Iván If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score -2):

Enter this in terminal,

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

It needs to download packages `Translation-en`. After downloading finishes, run

`sudo apt-get update`, you wont find this `Ign` messages.

Comment: -1 How did you get that idea?